# Open directory on startup?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm setting up a portable-apps install of Vs-code (using official Portable Mode from the docs)

I have set the git path, mingw bash shell path. and now i am trying to have Vs-code automatically open a specific directory on my USB
`\\Workspace\\`

I use `\\` as the root directory because i noticed it gets treated as the root of the drive in `settings.json`

The code block is my current `settings.json`

```
{
    //Set EXTERNAL term to msys
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "\\PortableApps\\msys64\\mingw64.exe",

    //Set INTERNAL term to msys
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "\\PortableApps\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["--login", "-i"],
    "terminal.integrated.env.windows":
    {
        "MSYSTEM": "MINGW64",
        "CHERE_INVOKING":"1"
    },

    //GIT Settings
    "git.enabled": true,
    "git.path": "\\PortableApps\\msys64\\usr\\bin\\git.exe",
    "git.defaultCloneDirectory": "\\Documents\\Workspace",

    //ANTI TELEMETRY
    "workbench.enableExperiments": false,
    "workbench.settings.enableNaturalLanguageSearch": false,
    "telemetry.enableCrashReporter": false,
    "telemetry.enableTelemetry": false,
    "npm.fetchOnlinePackageInfo": false,

    //Disable Updates
    "update.mode": "none",

    //Hidden Files
    "files.exclude": {
        "**/desktop.ini": true
    },

    //Enhance portability
    "window.restoreWindows": "folders",
    "files.hotExit": "off",

    //Custom setup
    "window.title": "${dirty}${activeFolderMedium} ${separator} ${activeEditorShort}",
    "workbench.startupEditor": "welcomePage",
}
```

The thing im trying to do that i need help figuring out how to do, is automatically opening `\\Workspace\\` when i open vscode. And no, a `.code-workspace` file wont work as it wont have the proper file associations.

Does anyone know what flag i need to use to open a specific directory on startup?